# How to prevent a base class from inheritance in C++?

Tags: c++, inheritance

I don't want to make the base class from being derived to a new class. Is there any way to achieve this?
I want to tell the compiler that you can't inherit the base class just like a final keyword in java

Comment: In c++11 you can use `class Base final {`

Comment: Not to be picky, but if a class can't be derived it can't be a base class,

Comment: Private contructor, like singletone design pattern

Comment: See this also https://www.interviewsansar.com/stop-a-class-to-be-inherited-cpp/ and this https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-prevent-class-inheritance-in-cplusplus

Comment: @IonutAlexandru one consequence of making the constructor private is that you cannot inherit from the class, but this does not mean that when you want a final class you should make the constructor private. A private constructor has other consequences

Comment: So guys, it seems declaring the class is final is the only option to prevent derived class from it

Answer (score 5):

You can mark the class as [`final`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final) to prevent derivation from it. E.g:

```
class A final { ... };
```

Comment: Just in case I would mention that `final` is available since c++ 11